# Есть ли альтернатива iframe для изолирования 2х и более приложений на фронте

Tags: веб-программирование, iframe, frontend

Есть некий `портал` в рамках которого реализуется различный функционал(отчеты,справочники,etc...)

Исторически сложилось так, что было принято решение о том, чтобы многочисленные части были `независимыми`, не только в плане структуры или архитектуры, но и стека технологий. Реализовано было с помощью `iframe` в котором открывалось `отдельное` веб-приложение. Такие приложения есть и на angular 1.x и 2.x, react, просто html+css статика и тд.

**Вопрос**: Существуют ли готовые решения организации такого подхода не используя `iframe`, какой то способ иметь в рамках одной вкладки 2 и более отдельных изолированных веб-приложения. Не всегда они будут отдаваться с одного веб-сервера.

Comment: Может, вы ищете [Shadow DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom)? Он позволяет сделать полную изоляцию тега относительно документа, в котором расположен, включая стили и скрипты. То есть, теоретически, в приложение на React вы сможете засунуть приложение на Angular через эту технологию.

Comment: Зачем искать альтернативу там, где и так всё чудесно? Тем более если сайты не взаимодействуют друг с другом в браузере.

Comment: @Sergey пока не взаимодействуют, хотя какое то взаимодействие всеже есть, между ними ходит авторизация.